# Assign variable with path in smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty

I want to check if file exists in template and for that I'd need a variable with path to the file

I have a loop {section name=i loop=$albums}

What I'd do in php:

```
$filename = $url . '/path/' . $albums[i].AID . '.jpg';
```

And I have the path to the file but I can't find a way to do this in smarty template

I have tried to do it inside of {php} tags

this->assign('filename', "$relative . '/media/albums/' . '$albums[i].AID' . 'jpg'");

But result is just

. '/media/albums/' . '.AID' . 'jpg'1

I also tried to do it with {assign var name=filename val=$relative . '/media/albums/' . '$albums[i].AID' . 'jpg'  and many variations of this, but the result is similar as with php tags.

I just can't get it to recognize the other variables.

Can this be done with smarty at all?

Comment: Looks as though you've got your quotes confused. Try: this->assign('filename', $relative . '/media/albums/' . $albums[i].AID.' . jpg');

Comment: Another format that might be a bit easier to read: this->assign('filename', "{$relative}/media/albums/{$albums[i].AID}. jpg");

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That sadly only leads to the same: /media/albums/AID . jpg

Comment: Then there is a problem with the variables $relative and $albums.

Comment: Nope, the variables were correct. I got it to work actually. The problem is smarty, it didn't work via {php} tags, had to do it via latter example and without $var . 'text' . $var

Comment: Instead just downvoting, I'd love to hear why? I see nothing wrong with the question. Or is this just some reddit style trolling? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed it. For anyone having similar problem in the future with smarty, use for example:

```
{assign var name=file val=$albums[i].AID}
{assign var name=filename val=/direct/localpath/public_html/media/albums/$file.jpg}
```

That worked for me.